# Dependency injection an object without all of its methods

Tags: php, dependency-injection

so a class:

```
class ToBeUsed
{
    private $a;

    public function setSomething($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function getSomething()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }
}
```

its beign created and updated:

```
$obj = new ToBeUsed();
$obj->setSomething('a');
```

and passed to another object

```
class UseIt
{
    /**
     * @var ToBeUsed
     */
    private $obj;

    public function __construct(ToBeUsed $obj)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function work()
    {
        $this->obj->getSomething();
        $this->obj->setSomething(); //// !!!!! THIS IS BAD!
    }
}
```

now a classic `DI` example, except that the passed object should be "dulled" - only some methods are allowed to use. E.g. `getSomething()` is allowed to use, but `setSomething()` is not. What pattern / practice can get away with it? There used to be `friend` classes is C but its Php...

Comment: As is PHP does not protect methods if your simply passing a class around, if you want restraints then add a [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) check, https://3v4l.org/8S3nr

Comment: You can always use an anonymous class proxying the ToBeUsed class but "disabling" the setter methods

Comment: @MarkBaker - that's a good Idea, Something like extend the class and have it throw an exception in the override of the `set` methods.

Comment: @MarkBaker - Do you mind if I add an example of this to my answer?

Comment: That's the basic premise I was thinking of.... as an extending class, it will share any typehinted signature, and overriding the setter methods to throw an exception was precisely what I was thinking - the only awkwardness would be methods defined as final - but feel free to add an example

Comment: There would still be an issue of using the set methods, this would be fine with a new object, but there is no way to bypass the restriction, within the scope of the same object.

Comment: Could use Reflection to turn the methods from `protected` to `public` when you want to use them, if they were set to protected.... not really a good way of doing this.

Comment: As a quick example, I was thinking of something like [this](https://3v4l.org/mIabU); although it isn't really proxying.... a true proxy would share an interface with the typehinted class, mimic the getters with a call to the original class, but not provide any setters

Comment: Cool I like it!, you know I have yet to use the dynamic classes in PHP7, were still on PHP 5.6 at my work on our main server.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something with Interfaces, it doesn't prevent a method form being used.  But "they" (whoever they is) would be using it outside of the Interface for `$obj`.

Like this:

```
class ToBeUsed implements ToBeUsedInterface
{
    private $a;

    public function getSomething()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }

    public function setSomething($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

interface ToBeUsedInterface{
    public function getSomething(); 
}
    
class UseIt
{
    /**
     * @var ToBeUsed
     */
    private $obj;

    public function __construct(ToBeUsedInterface $obj)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function work()
    {
        $this->obj->getSomething();
        $this->obj->setSomething(); //This now exists outside of the interface for $obj
    }
}
```

In terms of IDE's this would prevent the methods from auto-completing as well.

The only other thing I can think of, ( besides the other answer ) would be to set the method to `protected` and then use `ReflectionMethod` to change the viability, when you want to use it.

### Another Option, is Using Reflection

```
class ToBeUsed
{
    private $a;

    public function getSomething()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }

    protected function setSomething($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

$ToBeUsed = new ToBeUsed();

$ReflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod($ToBeUsed, 'setSomething');
$ReflectionMethod->setAccessible(true);
$ReflectionMethod->invoke($ToBeUsed, 'foo');

echo $ToBeUsed->getSomething();
```

Outputs:

```
foo
```

You can see it [live here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cc457833dcaadc5662b7561c74780707722760c)

And Obviously sense it's protected under normal conditions, it could not be used inside `UseIt`.  If I was going to use this for any amount of code, I would extend or wrap the Reflection class.  Just to make the call a bit more concise, like this:

```
class MyReflector
{
    public static function invoke($class, $method, ...$args)
    {
        $ReflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod($class, $method);
        $ReflectionMethod->setAccessible(true);
        $ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs($class, $args);
    }
}

$ToBeUsed = new ToBeUsed();

MyReflector::invoke($ToBeUsed,'setSomething', 'foo');
```

Please note I got all fancy with the variadic `...$arg` which is for PHP 5.6+  it just lets you do

```
 MyReflector::invoke($ToBeUsed,'setSomething', 'foo', 'bar');
```

And `$args` would be `['foo','bar']` in the first example it's just `['foo']` which can be used for `invokeArgs` for the second argument which takes an array of arguments to pass on to the actual method.

Comment: your interface is not implemented anywhere

Comment: and it doesn't work: `echo $this->obj->getSomething();
        $this->obj->setSomething('b'); 
        echo $this->obj->getSomething();` prints `ab`

Comment: What `doesn't work`, as I said It wont prevent the method from being used.  But it prevents it from showing auto complete for the method in IDE's and it would be bad practice to use a method in a class that is outside of a hinted interface, as it could change.

Comment: sorry, but then it is not an answer that solves the original problem

Comment: From a proper Programming perspective it does, as it would be improper to use methods of a class outside of a type hinted interface.

Comment: Well, its up to OP to decide, whether 'Soft Restriction' as your qualifies, but IMHO your solution does nothing except IDE fit. It wouldn't save neither OP, nor any colleague from calling `setSomething` outside of `ToBeUsed` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ToBeUsed
{
    private $a;

    public function setSomething($a)
    {
        $dbg = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS,2);
        if(count($dbg) > 1){
            return;
        }
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function getSomething()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }
}

class UseIt
{
    /**
     * @var ToBeUsed
     */
    private $obj;

    public function __construct(ToBeUsed $obj)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function work()
    {
        echo $this->obj->getSomething().PHP_EOL; // a
        $this->obj->setSomething('b'); // this does nothing
        echo $this->obj->getSomething().PHP_EOL; // a
    }
}

$obj = new ToBeUsed();
$obj->setSomething('a');

$obj2 = new UseIt($obj);
$obj2->work();
```

Alternatively, you can perform more complex checks on `debug_backtrace()` output.

Comment: This could cause a lot of potential side effects, if you use this class in say a controller.  For example, the targeting is too broad if `UseIt` is part of an Application section of an API, but there are System Parts of the API that would be allowed to call it. Depends on the "Use Case" the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yeah, but the "Use Case" is not clear from the original question. As I wrote: 'Alternatively, you can perform more complex checks on debug_backtrace() output'. By which I meant: "check actual values of returned array" :)

Comment: In what I outlined above there would be no way to know what name someone building `UseIt` as part of an API would take, so there is no way to exclude, therefor you would have to check what is allowed, which is cumbersome.